# Usos de la coma y el paréntesis

Tags: persona-gramatical

A veces cuando queremos agregar una frase en el medio de una oración, ya sea para aclarar algo o para introducir algo, como estoy haciendo ahora mismo con esta oración, se usa la coma o el paréntesis. Existe alguna regla que diga cuando usar coma y cuando usar paréntesis? O, no existe regla alguna? Por ejemplo, veamos un fragmento de una oración(la oración en realidad es tres paginas de largo):

[image]

¿Cómo podemos interpretar el uso de las comas en el fragmento? En ciertos pasajes del texto, ¿es posible sustituir el uso de las comas por paréntesis? ¿Es posible, en este caso, también haber podido usar el uso de "-" (como en: texto- ##### - continuación del texto)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de paréntesis en lugar de comas implica un mayor grado de aislamiento del enunciado que encierran con respecto al texto en que se inserta, y permite el uso en su interior de signos de puntuación propios (incluyendo comas).

Puedes consultar más sobre esto [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XFiqsCjr2D68AoepU2).

Comment: Entiendo. Una aclaración, ¿podría usar coma en vez de paréntesis en la línea 6 de tu respuesta?

Comment: Sí, podría usar comas. He escogido el uso de paréntesis porque la frase me parecía ya un poco larga y se me antojaba que otra coma la haría más dificil de leer. Pero es una decisión que yo mismo he cuestionado. :-)

Comment: Es cierto que el uso de paréntesis y comas es ambiguo, hay que aclarar que la función de la coma es separar las oraciones para que no exista confusión en lo que se está escribiendo. Concordando con el comentario anterior, el paréntesis es para plantear una idea aislada del tema central, una característica que sirve para esclarecer "el contexto" en el que se está hablando. 
Por ejemplo: "En el terremoto de Chile (2010), la ciudad de Santiago se vio afectada por el corte de luz" (oración inventada).